# If g and h agree on a set do they agree on its closure?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces. Let $A \subset X$. Let $f : A → Y$ be a continuous map. Assume that there
exists a continuous function $g : cl(A) → Y$ such that $g|A = f$.

(a) Let $h : cl(A) → Y$ be another continuous map such that $h|A = f$ . Is $h = g$ always?

(b) Suppose in part (a) additionally we are given that $Y$ is Hausdorff. Then is $h = g$?

I have solved (b) but (a) seems too difficult. I tried giving a counterexample with Zariski Topology but can't.

Comment: What does the notation $g \rvert A$ mean?

Comment: g restricted to A.

Comment: Don't you mean $g:X\rightarrow Y$? If $A$ is its domain then $g|A$ is not a proper restriction.

Comment: That's right! g:X→Y

Comment: Is there a hypothesis relating to A being a compact subset of X?

Comment: In the question, you haven't stated that $X$ is the closure of $A$, as you have in the title.

Comment: I have edited it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=Y=\{a,b\}$ with the T$_0$ topology $\{\emptyset,X,\{a\}\}$. Define $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=a$. The functions are continuous, and they agree on the open set $A=\{a\}$, but they do not agree on $\bar A=X$.

Here is a T$_1$ example. Let $A$ be a countably infinite set. Let $p,q$ be two distinct points not in $A$. Let $Y=A\cup\{p,q\}$ with the topology
$$\tau=\{U\subseteq Y:\text{ either }U\subseteq A\text{ or else }A\setminus U\text{ is finite}\}.$$
Then $Y$ is a T$_1$ space but is not Hausdorff, and $A$ is a dense open subset of $X$. Let $X=Y\setminus\{q\}$ with the subspace topology; $X$ is a compact metrizable space, and $A$ is dense in $X$. Let $g:X\to Y$ be the inclusion map $g(x)=x$. Let $h:X\to Y$ be the same except that $h(p)=q$. Then $g$ and $h$ are continuous maps which agree on the set $A$ but not on its closure.

Comment: What is the topology of Y, $T_2$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ have the same topology.

Comment: The topology is $T_0$, not $T_1$.